# Fully wiping out installed Ubuntu

Tags: system-installation, 22.04, kubuntu, delete, disk-formatting

I have an existing pre-installed Ubuntu that I wan't to make sure its completely wiped out.
If I do an installation of Kubuntu guided using the entire disk + encryption LVM would that do the trick or could parts of that original Ubuntu not be wiped out? If so is there anything I need to do to ensure full cleanup?

Just for context: there are no data in that pre-installed Ubuntu. All It is just that for security I want to make sure anything fishy (program I mean) pre-installed does not make it after the new install

The output of `lsblk`

[image]

Comment: Usually even just a full formatting is enough to wipe off sensitive data.  Shred will do multiple overwrites, but not sure the bad blocks get rewritten.  If you're worried about NSA inspection, the tool to use is a hammer.

Comment: @ubfan1: I updated the post. It is not about data I care about. It is more like overly cautious from security perspective

Comment: From a security perspective "parts of that original Ubuntu not be wiped out" is a vague requirement. To be secure, you want all data loaded and run from disk to be in your control. If you zero then format the entire disk capacity with FDE/LVM, you would clearly have every byte under your control. Other precautions might be preventing the mounting of unknown partitions, and checking whether the hard disk firmware is vulnerable to malware

Comment: @DanielT: How do I `zero then format the entire disk capacity with FDE/LVM`? Is the `FDE/LVM` what I did? I.e guided installation using the whole disk with LVM and encryption?

Comment: You can use https://askubuntu.com/a/142862/1004020 to zero the entire capacity, then use the usual installer with FDE/LVM

Comment: @DanielT:FDE/LVM is guided install of whole disk with LVM and encryption option?

Comment: @DanielT: How do I use `dd` to zero out the disk if I am already using the disk? Won't `dd` block trying to zero the disk it is currently installed?

Comment: Yes, it is indeed the guided install. FDE/LVM was just an abbreviation of your "using the entire disk + encryption LVM". Your Ubuntu will crash if you try to zero the disk while using it. Boot into a LiveUSB, and run the `dd` to zero

Comment: @DanielT: Should I be doing `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdX` on each device reported by `lsblk`?

Comment: If you have only one disk named sda, you can just use the "sda" without the number, to zero the entire disk. If `lsblk` gave multiple disks such as `sdb`, make sure you know what the disk is for before zeroing it, to avoid data loss

Comment: @DanielT: I don't care about data loss. What I am confused what happens when doing `dd` on the device that is under use. Will `dd` stop working? Will the whole system start crashing?

Comment: The whole system will crash as soon as it tries to swap in any page that was paged out. Furthermore if a program appends a single byte to a file that was already overwritten, the entire block containing it will get written back.

Comment: @DanielT:I added the output of `lsblk` to the post.

Comment: @DanielT:So basically if I only run `dd` and nothing else, provided that the OS doesn't swap a page `dd` will zero out everything and the system will appear as running till I reboot?

Comment: According to you `lsblk`, you only need to zero `nvme0n1`. What is your use case for asking about the specific way that `dd` breaks a running system? I personally wouldn't try and I mostly just know that it's undefined behavior so anything could happen

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151421/discussion-between-jim-and-daniel-t).

Comment: @DanielT: I mention the whole process in my answer. Thank you!

Comment: @ubfan1: Out of curiosity, if full formatting, shred and/or dd erase everything why a hammer is required as an extreme? Can data be still recovered by experts if e.g. the HD was wiped out with zeros?

Comment: @Jim https://security.stackexchange.com/q/12503/284633

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I followed @DanielT suggestion:

1. I booted from the USB and selected `Try Kubuntu`.
2. I opened the console and I typed: `lsblk` to see which device to wipe out (see screenshot in my post)
3. I run `dd` to wipe out the drive taking care not to choose the USB and corrupt the installer. Although many answers mention an example by using `/dev/zero` seems none of the answers are complete. The usual answer that says: `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdX bs=4MB status=progress` results in out of space error because `/dev/zero` is infinite stream. I run `dd` as follows:
   `sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/nvme0n1 bs=4M count=$(sudo blockdev --getsize64 /dev/nvme0n1) status=progress`. The `count` ensures that we stop once we reach the limit of the device. Also note I had to use `/dev` prefix even though it is not mentioned in `lsblk`
4. I rebooted
5. I went to BIOS to boot from USB. The hard disk was not visible at all as bootable
6. In the installation screen, unlike earlier that there was a reported about existing partitions/installations on the hard disk, this time the `Before` section was totally empty (first time shown like this as I run the install multiple times)
7. I did guided use whole disk + encrypted LVM
8. Finished the installation and started the system
   All worked fine!